# Consulta por fecha de inicio en hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy realizando consultas a una base de datos a través de eclipse utilizando Hibernate. En una de esas consultas me gustaría extraer la información de un registro introduciendo uno de sus campos, en este caso la fecha de inicio del prestamo de un libro. Hasta ahora tengo esto.

```
public static void consulta(String a ) {
    String c ="select fechaInicio from Prestamos where fechaInicio like 'a'   ";

    System.out.print("Introduzca fecha: ");
    a = teclado.next();


    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query q= session.createQuery(c);
    List results = q.list();
    Iterator Prestamositerator = results.iterator();
    while (Prestamositerator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(Prestamositerator.next());
    }
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: Y cual es el error que te da? Por qué en String c le pasas la variable a entre comillas simples? No sería más bien --> String c ="select fechaInicio from Prestamos where fechaInicio like '" + a + "' "; ?

Comment: No creo que `LIKE` te vaya a funcionar así en fechas. O comparas con `<` o `>` o conviertes las fecha a varchar y ahí utilizas `LIKE`

Comment: Pero el dato fecha_Inicio es tipo Date y lo que trato es de introduciendo una determinada fecha a través de una consulta me muestre los datos de los demas campos. No sé si debo utilizar gregorianCalendar para hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que haría sería:

Primero transformar a Date el String que recoges por pantalla (tendrás que manejar la excepción ParseException)

```
System.out.print("Introduzca fecha: ");
String a = teclado.next();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date fecha = sdf.parse(a);
```

Después a tu query le pasas un parámetro de forma que se encarge el solo de transformar el Date anterior al formato de la base de datos

```
String c ="select fechaInicio from Prestamos where fechaInicio = :fechaInicio";

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Query q= session.createQuery(c);
q.setDate("fechaInicio", a); //Aquí le das el valor al parámetro de la query
List results = q.list();

Iterator Prestamositerator = results.iterator();
while (Prestamositerator.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(Prestamositerator.next());
}
session.close();
```

Espero que funcione.